# Why doesn't show widget title in WordPress 5.8?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, wordpress-gutenberg

I create a custom theme that I want to be compatible with WordPress 5.8 version. I register a sidebar via functions.php in theme. It's working on 5.7 perfectly but When I switched WordPress version 5.7 to 5.8 then Widgets editor switch to Block Editor. Widget Title now shows in the widget and can't update the title.
functions.php

```
function unfold_sidebar_registration() {

    // Sidebar #1.
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'        => __( 'Sidebar', 'unfold' ),
            'id'          => 'sidebar-1',
            'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be displayed in the sidebar.', 'unfold' ),
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title subheading heading-size-3">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s"><div class="widget-content">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
        )
    );

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'unfold_sidebar_registration' );
```

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Comment: Please check this post. I did not get this as mentioned.
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/widget-title-is-gone/